# Getting value of JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

I have below JSON output and want to get specific value based on input,

```
"quotes": {
  "USDAUD": 1.278342,
  "USDEUR": 0.908019,
  "USDGBP": 0.645558,
  "USDPLN": 3.731504
}
```

Now i have user input of USD and GBP

How can i get only specific value from "quotes",

I tried as below,

```
from = $("#from option:selected").val();  //this is USD
to = $("#to option:selected").val();  //this is GBP
```

then i made a string by

```
output = to + from;
```

and tried to get value in console

```
console.log(json.quotes);  //this gives complete output in console
console.log(json.quotes.output); //but with this i could not get value of USDGBP
```

How can i get required value from JSON object?

Comment: question is a bit unclear

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause output is a string you can not just `json.quotes.output` you need to put it in squarely brackets like:

```
json.quotes[output]
```

```js
var json = {
  "quotes": {
    "USDAUD": 1.278342,
    "USDEUR": 0.908019,
    "USDGBP": 0.645558,
    "USDPLN": 3.731504
  }
};

var from = 'GBP';
var to = 'USD';
var output = to + from;
console.log(output);

console.log(json.quotes);  //this gives complete output in console
console.log(json.quotes[output]); //but with this i could not get value of USDGBP
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, objects and arrays have a very similar usage.

So lookup into the created object as an array:

```
output = from + to;
if (quotes[output]!==undefined)
{
    var yourValue=quotes[output];
}
```